# Importing 'Devices and Printers' from one server to another

Tags: windows, drivers, printing, printer, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a windows server 2003 that is in the process of getting replaced.

It has a long list of printers connected; I'm looking for some method of 'importing' the printers from the 2003 to my new windows 2008 server.

Is there a directory where all the device && printer and drivers are stored?

Comment: You can run [`printbrm.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc722360.aspx) on the 2008 and migrate the 2003 server's printers/ports/drivers over to another server. There's a GUI too if you need - `printbrmuii.exe`.

Comment: Why did you not post this as an answer? I will try in a bit - and if it works that's really great advice! 

Thank you!

Comment: I was probably on mobile and didn't want to futz with formatting up a proper answer, sorry. Also a typo in my initial comment, the UI binary is `C:\windows\system32\printbrmui.exe` the command line verison is `C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\PrintBrm.exe`.